# counting the letters "a" in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, count

I have a task to count many "a" letters in an array

so this is my code

```
#include <iostream>

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int i;
    int ch[10];
    cout<<"enter 10 letters"<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        cin>>ch[i];
    }
    cout<<endl;cout<<endl;
    cout<<"this is the letter you entered"<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        cout<<(ch[i])<<endl;
    }
    vector<int> a = ch[10];
    int cnt;
    cnt = count(a.begin(), a.end(), "a");
    cout<<"many a's are = "<<cnt<<endl;

}
```

but it give me error 
[Error] conversion from 'int' to non-scalar type 'std::vector' requested

please help me,
reference my code from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cpp_standard_library/cpp_algorithm_count.htm

Comment: Try `std::copy(std::begin(ch),std::end(ch),std::begin(a));` instead of `vector<int> a = ch[10];`.

Comment: Expression `ch[10]` does not represent the array as a whole. Also, distinguish `int` and `char`, and character literal and string literal.

Comment: `vector<int> a = ch[10];` Has 2 errors on it's own: 1) No conversion exists from an `int` (11th element of `ch` array) to `std::vector<int>` 2) You are referencing an element outside of the bounds of the array - invoking undefined behavior. I would suggest you read a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: The name of the array is `ch`, not `ch[10]`, and `"a"` is an array of characters, not a character.

Comment: no no no, I mean, I'll insert a character a into an array via cin, a also variable

Comment: I do not understand c ++ but this is my homework from lecturer

Answer (score 2):

For starters the array `ch` should be declared like

```
char ch[10];
^^^^
```

if you are going to type letters as the input.

This statement

```
vector<int> a = ch[10];
```

does not make sense. The initializer of the vector is non-existent element of the array `ch`. And moreover the class template `std::vector` does not have a non-explicit constructor that converts an object of the type `int` to the type `std::vector<int>`.

And in this statement

```
cnt = count(a.begin(), a.end(), "a");
```

you are trying to count how many times the string literal `"a"` that has the type `const char[2]` is encountered in an object of the type `std::vector<int>`.

There is no need to declare a vector that to count occurrences of the letter `'a'`. You could just write

```
#include <iterator>

//...

char ch[10];

//...

auto cnt = std::count( std::begin( ch ), std::end( ch ), 'a' );
```